# What are the steps to use linkedin people search api?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am trying to access linkedin people search api via
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?first-name=Clair

But it returns me

```
<error>
<status>401</status>
<timestamp>1422599405748</timestamp>
<request-id>3O1KI50MDV</request-id>
<error-code>0</error-code>
<message>Unknown authentication scheme</message>
</error>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have never used the api.Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your app with LinkedIn and get their approval (they call it vetted access) to be able to use people search.

Check https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

Comment: @Cgraphics According to [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) post, People Search API will no longer be available after May 12th, 2015. So, the documentation for it is no longer available.

Comment: as of now this is what you are looking for... https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

Answer (score 1):

I work at [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com) and we recently added [LinkedIn Public Search Results Scraper API](https://serpapi.com/linkedin-search) .
You can check out this [example](https://serpapi.com/search?engine=linkedin&first_name=Jimmy&last_name=Neutron) in playground. Response for a profile found contains name, occupation, location, last_job, last education thumbnail and link.

Comment: in October 2021 this API is closed: https://serpapi.com/linkedin-profile "Our LinkedIn API is currently disabled for scability issues."

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn's People Search API has not been available to the open developer community since May, 2015.

You can apply to be a developer partner at: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: Link not working.